# Hibernate transformed bean attachment to session

Tags: hibernate

Is the output from stateful session query, which result has undergone result transformation, ie ResultTransformer is set, attached to hibernate session? To further give detail to the question, will there be dirty update if we modify the transformed output? Needless to say, transformed output can be any bean, it can be a map also, and of course it can be an entity class instance registered in session factory.

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to answer this simply to try it? Get one of your result objects, make a change to it, and try to persist it, and you'll find out pretty quickly if its attached to the session or not because it'll either go through and result in a change in a db table, or it'll throw an exception.

Comment: I will probably be able to try it only the day after tomorrow. It was an interview question shared to me and i thought the answer is 'detached'. Unfortunately i cant find the answer from mr google also

Comment: It's not a fair interview question, so you might want to give that company the slip. I've worked in the past as a trainer delivering hibernate courses to major corporations, and I've worked closely, for years, on hibernate systems with JBoss people who are really close to hibernate, yet I couldn't answer this without googling it. Anyone who expects you to hold knowledge like this in you head is quite unreasonable -- you're lucky you've discovered that early before signing up for a nightmare team.

Comment: For those interested, have tested this and have confirmed that the transformed bean is not attached to first level session. Cheers